# invalid context 0x0 CGContextDrawImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

After some runs of the following block of code, I get an invalid context 0x0 for CGContextDrawImage. This code is in a user-defined method within a UIViewController. I essentially capture an image from taking a still image using AVFoundation and take that image for reading pixel hex data value. Below is the code I have written:

```
AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput.connections)
{
    for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts])
    {
        if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] )
        {
            videoConnection = connection;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (videoConnection) { break; }
}
[stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
{
    CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment( imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
    NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
    image2 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
}];

CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,bitsPerComponent,bytesPerRow, colorSpace,kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
```

Why am I getting an invalid context 0x0 for CGContextDrawImage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CGBitmapContextCreate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGBitmapContextCreate) returns `NULL` if it is unable to create the requested context. `CGContextDrawImage` is essentially complaining about `context` being `NULL`.

Comment: How can I make it not NULL? Like is there a way to force CGBitmapContextCreate to return a valid context always?

Comment: One or more of the parameters that are being passed in must not be correct. The documentation doesn't really say what to look for if it returns `NULL`, just that it wasn't able to create the context. I'd say set breakpoint on that line and see what the parameters are vs. what you're expecting to be passing in.

Comment: It appears that image2 is not valid. Why is that causing an issue?

Comment: `image2` is set asynchronously (`captureStillImageAsynchronously...`), but you're not waiting for the operation to complete. Depending on the context in which this is executing, the solution might be as easy as just moving the last four lines into the completion handler for the async operation, but if you need to have it bone before the current method exits, then you may have to block until the async work is complete, etc.

Comment: Thanks it appears to be fixed after moving the four lines into the completion handler. What exactly happens in the state that it's in now, not being in the handler block?

Comment: In the code in the question, the method continues after calling `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection`, so the data hasn't been loaded and assigned to the variable yet, so you run into null-related issues.

Comment: Ahh, so the code in the completion handler is run in a separate thread is what you're saying correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly! The thread that called the async didn't stop running, so it wouldn't be able to run the code in the completion block itself, which leaves it to be executed by the thread that serviced the async operation.